# Using the ShareCompat library from an App Widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I would like to create a pending intent for my app widget view that will launch a sharing intent.  The problem is that there is no reference to any activity in the *android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider* class.  The code below does not work because I don't have access to the MainMenuActivity class.  Any ideas, is this even possible?

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MainMenuActivity.this)
                   .setText("Some text")
                   .setType("text/plain")
                   .getIntent();

PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, shareIntent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, actionPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the `Context` supplied as a parameter to your `onUpdate()` method to the `from()` method on `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, it looks like `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` will only work with `Activity`, not a generic `Context` like most other things in Android. Hence, you will not be able to use it from an app widget.

Comment: If I pass in the context like so `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from((Activity)context)` I receive a ClassCastException

Comment: @user922295: Sorry -- I thought it took a regular `Context`. I think you are out of luck.